# How I can prevent bcrypt from slowing down my site?

Tags: node.js, angular, performance, hash, bcrypt

I am working on a project using Angular and Node.js. I use bcrypt to secure my different passwords. But I have one issue which I am still struggling on.

When a new user has to register, the process of hashing the typed password takes a lot of time so that it slows down my frontend. It's the same for the sign-in method.

According to some resources, it's about the bcrypt "hash and compare" methods.
Can someone tell me how to use these methods without slowing down my website?

Comment: What resources? How are you _currently_ using those methods? How slow is slow, and how much of that is really bcrypt's fault?

Comment: To some extent, bcrypt is slow by design, to make brute force attacks more difficult. How many rounds of bcrypt are you using? And how "slow" is it exactly?

Comment: Ideally *some* of the computational burden should be offloaded to the client. More modern password hashing algorithms like Argon2 offer a feature called "server relief" that allows this to happen. See for example [libsodium's api support](https://doc.libsodium.org/password_hashing/#server-relief) for this.

Answer (score 5):

Bcrypt has a "work factor" (the node.js library seems to call this "saltRounds"), which defines how many iterations it performs, and thus how slow it is.

The default work factor is usually 10, so you could reduce this to make the hashing process faster. Note that if you have existing hashes in your database, they'll continue to use the old work factor until they're replaced - usually by changing the passwords.

However, you need to consider that being slow is *the main  point* of bcrypt. The faster the hashing process is, the faster it is for an attacker to try and crack the hashes if they can obtain them. This is one of the main reasons that MD5 and SHA-* hashes are not recommended - they're designed to be fast, which is exactly what you don't want.

Having said that, it's all about finding a balance. If your work factor is too high then not only does it slow down you site, but it can also introduce a DoS risk if an attacker can max out your CPU by repeatedly making login attempts.

Do some benchmarking on your server, and maybe try a work factor of 9 or 8 to find a point that works for you.

Comment: I am really Thankfull for your returns. I finally solved this issue by using a loader.  When the user finish to type the password and submit it, I run a loader(spinner on my frontend) that user concentrate on it before the hashing process end.